# Collapsable/hidden text boxes in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

If I want to add in a lot more information to a particular box, is it possible to create a hidden “note” section where I can add more detail without cluttering up the flowchart?

Comment: What about using an addition layer just for comments?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following:
https://about.draw.io/interactive-diagrams-with-custom-links-and-actions/

Recommendation: Define a new layer called "Information". Add textBox visually close to your object you wish to display text.  Put the textBox on the "Information" layer.  Add an object that looks like letter I or ? .  Modify the URL of this object to toggle layer to also be on your primary display layer.

Answer (score -3):

I use tooltips to hide too much additional text.